# How are third party controls used in Xamarin applications?

Tags: xamarin, controls

Since I have limited experience with Xamarin I'm not sure if this is a simple or complex question ...

If I want to create an app for Android, iOS and Windows Phone but I have a third party control or library that I need to include how is that done?

For example say I have want to use the company XYZ's SuperPicture control that has some functions on it to say load images, crop them, etc.

- Does that control or library have to be implemented by XYZ for each platform?
- Or does XYZ have to provide a Xamarin 'enabled' control\library?
- Or do I have to wrap it myself in some way?
- What if the functions on each platform vary slightly, either by name or functionality?
- Does Xamarin 3 (with Xamarin forms) makes this easier?

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of ways this can be done:

- a component may be available in Xamarin's [Component Store](http://components.xamarin.com) for one or more platforms
- a component may be available via nuget in a per-platform dll or cross-platform PCL
- a native (Java JAR or iOS lib/framework) library will need to be [bound for use in Xamarin](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/).  Some companies may provide Xamarin bindings, or you may find an existing binding that someone in the community has shared, or you may need to do it yourself
- if the API is not the same for every platform, you will need to write platform specific code to work with it, or create a common facade layer, etc
- Xamarin 3 does not fundamentally change this issue, although it did introduce support for [shared projects](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/shared_projects/), which is another way to do cross platform code

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin components are developed on a per-platform basis. If it's cross-platform, it was developed on each platform independently.

If there is an existing control you want to use for a platform, Xamarin does provide the ability to write a wrapper (assuming none exists) for use in a Xamarin project.

With Xamarin.Forms (in Xamarin 3) you could develop a component that was cross-platform, as long as it uses the available X.Forms components (and implemented properties). Though realistically you will still have some amount of custom code for each platform due to the limited controls and properties X.Forms gives you.